# How to make Django sqlclear output CASCADE for dependent relationships

Tags: python, django

I have a number of models containing foreign keys and many to many (m2m) relationships in a Django project.  When I try and use the sqlclear command from manage.py i receive the error:

```
ERROR:  cannot drop table appname_tablename because other objects depend on it
```

Is there a way to have Django add CASCADE to the output so dependent tables can be dropped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute resulting DROP TABLE script several times until all tables will be dropped. Is this a problem for you?

**EDITED**

You can overwrite [sql_delete](http://djangoapi.quamquam.org/trunk/django.core.management.sql-pysrc.html#sql_delete) in [django.core.management.sql](http://pydoc.net/Django/1.0/django.core.management.commands.sqlclear) with:

```
...
if cursor and table_name_converter(model._meta.db_table) in table_names: 
    # Drop the table now 
    output.append('%s %s %s;' % (style.SQL_KEYWORD('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS'), #<-!
                                 style.SQL_TABLE(qn(model._meta.db_table)),
                                 style.SQL_KEYWORD('CASCADE')))    #<-!
...
```

Comment: I mean in reality I could write a shell script which could regex "; to " CASCADE; as I am piping the output of sqlclear to dbshell, though a --cascade option which would be much more elegant and idiomatic is what I was hoping for

Answer (score 7):

Why not use sed ?

```
>>> ./manage.py sqlclear testapp | sed 's/";/" CASCADE;/' 
BEGIN;
DROP TABLE "testapp_person" CASCADE;
DROP TABLE "testapp_post" CASCADE;
DROP TABLE "testapp_userprofile" CASCADE;
DROP TABLE "testapp_school" CASCADE;
DROP TABLE "testapp_events" CASCADE;
DROP TABLE "testapp_uploadmodel" CASCADE;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: exactly what I thought - thanks for clarifying this one though I was seeking a 'native' Django solution which is why I accepted the answer from @danihp